# How to prove that for a closed set C, a limit point x of C is in C

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

The definition for an open set is: for a normed linear space $X$, a set $C$ is open if for all point $x$ in $C$, there exists an open ball in $C$ that contains $x$. A closed set is defined to be a set such that its complement in $X$ is an open set.

How do we prove that for a closed set $C$, it contains all limit points in $C$?

This a very elementary analysis problem. I have an idea of constructing a sequence of points to show that $C^c$ is an open set, but I'm not able to write a very rigorous proof. Can anyone help me to write a rigorous proof here?

Comment: Usually it is easier to work when the ball is centered in $x$.

Comment: Well, a proof by contradiction seems a good idea to start.  Assume there is a limit point of $C$ not in $C$.  It is sufficient to show that that implies $C^c$ is not open.  If we call that limit point $p$, as $p\not \in C$ we know $p \in C^c$.  If $C^c$ were open then what happens.  And as $p$ is a limit point of $C$ what happens.  Are they compatible?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by "limit points in $C$" you mean the points that are limits of convergent sequences $x_n \in C$.

So, suppose you have a sequence $x_n \in C$ converging to some $x \in X$. By assuming $C$ is has open complement, you want to conclude that $x \in C$. You can do that by contradiction... assume $x \not \in C$, and reach a contradiction: $\exists n,\, x_n \not \in C$.

After doing that, you look at your proof and realize you do not need a "contradiction", because you do not need to assume $x_n \in C$, in the first place... :-)

So, take $x_n \in X$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x \not \in C$. That is, $x \in C^c$. Since the complement is open, there is a ball centered in $x$ such that $B \in C^c$. By the definition of convergence, there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that from that point ahead ($n \geq N$) you have that $x_n \in B \subset C^c$. That is, the sequence $x_n$ is not in $C$. And that proves that any convergent sequence in $C$ must converge to a point in $C$.

You do not need to construct a sequence. You construct a sequence to prove the reverse implication. If $C$ is sequentially closed, then its complement is open. In this case, you assume $C^c$ is not open. Then you choose a point not in the interior of $C^c$ and build a sequence in $C$ that converges to this point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of points in the closed set $C$ converging to a point $x$. If $x\in C^\complement$ then, since $C^\complement$ is open, there is an open ball of $x$ with radius, say, $\varepsilon$, that is contained in $C^\complement$. But since $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, there is an $x_m$ at distance less than $\varepsilon$ from $x$. Thus $x_m$ is in the open ball and is an element of $C^\complement$, a contradiction, so $x$ can't be in $C^\complement$ and hence $x\in C$.